# MS Flow to add external users in SharePoint Online user group

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow, microsoft-forms

I have created MS form and I want to add user in SharePoint user group as per email field of MS Form.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an action called "Add User to SharePoint Group" in MS Flow, you can use it.

There are similar posts about this topic, you can refer to them:
[Add User to SharePoint Group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/plumsailsp/#add-user-to-sharepoint-group)
[Microsoft Flow – Add user to SharePoint Group](https://emadgabriel.com/2019/01/04/microsoft-flow-add-user-to-sharepoint-group/)
[Flow to add user to old school SP People and Groups using REST API?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Flow-Discussion/Flow-to-add-user-to-old-school-SP-People-and-Groups-using-REST/td-p/122768)

Comment: I referred second link but for non-Microsoft account it's not working. I am getting error: user does not exists

Comment: The user has to exist in your AzureAD before flow can permission the account.